# issue with edge_ngram tokenizer IN Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an edge ngram tokenizer in order to provide partial matching.
My documents look like

```
Name
Labson series LTD 2014
Labson PLO LTD 2014A
Labson PLO LTD 2014-I
Labson PLO LTD. 2014-II
```

My mapping is as follows

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 40,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "title": "Labson Series LTD 2014" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/2
{
  "title": "Labson PLO LTD 2014A" 
}


PUT my_index/doc/3
{
  "title": "Labson PLO LTD 2014-I" 
}


PUT my_index/doc/4
{
  "title": "Labson PLO LTD. 2014-II" 
}
```

The following query gives me 3 documents which is correct (`Labson PLO LTD 2014A`, `Labson PLO LTD 2014-I`, `Labson PLO LTD. 2014-II`)

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "labson plo", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I type in `Labson PLO 2014A` it gives me 0 documents

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Labson PLO 2014A", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect this to return 1 document `Labson PLO LTD 2014A`, but for some reason it seems like it is not indexing the digits in token. Let me know if i am missing thing anything over here.

Answer (score 1):

In your `autocomplete_search` you are using `lowercase` tokeinzer.
which performs the function of `Letter Tokenizer` and `Lower Case Token Filter` together .

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3//analysis-lowercase-tokenizer.html

Now lets see what `Letter Tokenizer` does.

> The letter tokenizer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-letter-tokenizer.html

so in your case when you queried.

> "query": "Labson PLO 2014A",

The query actually become

> "+title:labson +title:plo +title:a"

since the letter tokenizer dropped 2014. now your index tokens does not contain a token with just the letter `a`. that is why you did not get any results back.

you can analyze your query like this in kibana

```
POST my_index/_validate/query?explain
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Labson PLO 2014a", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you will see 2014 is getting dropped. from the final query.

Also to see what the letter tokenizer produces use the following query

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "letter",
  "text": "Labson PLO LTD 2014a"
}
```